# Como puedo hacer para que mi objeto (ventana Toplevel) me devuelva un str cuando la llame? en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, impresion

Tengo dificultades para poder hacer funcionar este código. En sí el código realiza lo que necesito (que es crear nombres de columnas para una tabla SQLite) pero al llamarlo, no me devuelve lo que necesito.
En un principio realicé este código pero como una ventana principal de tkinter y funcionaba perfecto, pero cuando intenté "mejorarlo" utilizando una ventana emergente me encuentro con este inconveniente. No se por qué no puedo hacer que este objeto me devuelva lo que quiero con el método **str** .
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import re
```

Crea los valores para la tabla en una ventana secundaria

```
class Valores(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("Creador de etiquetas")
        self.config(width = 300, height = 300)

        self.etiqueta = tk.StringVar()
        self.resultado = ""
        self.mostrar = ""

        self.titulo = ttk.Label(self, text = "Ingresá tus campos de medidas")
        self.titulo.place(x = 8, y = 8)

        self.focus()
        self.grab_set()
        #self.titulo.config(fg = "black", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 13))

        self.ingresa_datos()
        self.poner_botones()

    def ingresa_datos(self):

        ttk.Label(self, text = "Nombre columna").place(x= 10, y = 50)
        ttk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.etiqueta).place(x= 115, y = 50)

    def carga_datos(self): #Guarda lass etiquetas en una variable

        if re.search(" " + self.etiqueta.get() + " ", self.resultado, re.IGNORECASE) is None:             
        #se asegura que se ingresen campos únicos

            if self.resultado == "":

                self.resultado = " " + self.etiqueta.get() + " " + "REAL"

                self.mostrar = self.etiqueta.get()
            else:

                self.resultado += ", " + self.etiqueta.get() + " " + "REAL"

                self.mostrar += "\n" + self.etiqueta.get()

        else:

            if self.etiqueta.get() == "":

                messagebox.showwarning("Adevertencia", "No se permiten etiquetas en blanco")

            else:

                messagebox.showwarning("Adevertencia", "Campo ya ingresado")

        self.etiqueta.set("")

        ttk.Label(self, text = "Etiquetas añiadidas").place(x = 5, y = 120) #Etiqueda
        info = ttk.Label(self)
        info.place(x = 115, y = 120)
        info.config(text = "".join(self.mostrar)) #Muestra las etiquetas añiadidas

    def eliminar_etiqueta(self): #Elimina etiquetas!!!!    

        if self.etiqueta.get() != "" and re.search(self.etiqueta.get(), self.resultado,     re.IGNORECASE) is not None:

            self.resultado = self.resultado.replace(self.etiqueta.get() + " " + "REAL", "")
            self.mostrar = self.mostrar.replace(self.etiqueta.get(), "")

            self.etiqueta.set("")

            messagebox.showinfo("Eliminar etiqueta", "Etiqueta eliminada con éxito")

        else:

            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "No se puede eliminar dicho campo, vuelva a intentarlo")
            self.etiqueta.set("")

    def poner_botones(self):

        boton_ingresar = ttk.Button(self, text = "Ingresar", command = self.carga_datos)
        boton_ingresar.place(x= 50, y = 90)

        boton_eliminar = ttk.Button(self, text = "Eliminar", command = self.eliminar_etiqueta)
        boton_eliminar.place(x= 120, y = 90)

        boton_terminar = ttk.Button(self, text = "Terminar", command = lambda: self.destroy())
        boton_terminar.place(x= 190, y = 90)
```

La idea es que al llamar a este objeto pueda obtener en el formato deseado para construir una tabla en formato SQLite

```
    def __str__(self):

        if re.search(", ,", self.resultado) is not None:

            self.resultado = self.resultado.replace(", ,", ",")

        return self.resultado #ESTO ES LO QUE QUIERO QUE ME DEVUELVA Y NO LO HACE
```

Lo que no puedo lograr es que al imprimir este objeto me imprima self.resultado, ya que me lo imprime en blanco, como si no hubiese nada.
Es como que realiza esta función inmediatamente la llamo y no cuando termino de cargar los datos en la variable self.resultado.

```
#La idea es llamar a este objeto desde otro archivo que ya tiene la ventana principal
#Acá agrego esto como para que sea funcional el código

raiz = tk.Tk()

def boton_aca():

    print(Valores()) #Esto lo devuelve vacio

ttk.Button(raiz, text = "ACA", command = boton_aca).pack()

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: No entiendo al 100% tu pregunta, así que perdón si digo cualquier cosa. El método str NO hace que el objeto se comporte como cadena. Para obtener a tu objeto en forma de cadena tenés que usar la función str.

Comment: Según veo si te devuelve el resultado de `self.resultado` solo que su valor es un string vacio y por eso pareciera que no te imprime nada. Intenta cambiarle el valor por defecto que le has asignado y mira a ver si te lo devuelve

Comment: Claro, ese es el problema que tengo, es como que al llamar a la función me devuelve inmediatamente el valor de self.resultado, no espera a que le cargue los datos. Eso es lo que no puedo solucionar. @multiple probé con eso y sigue devolviéndome un string vacío.  Gracias